# Select features with same value in a given column

Tags: arcgis-desktop, query, select-by-attribute, unique-value

I first tried writing this post in generalities but realized it was more confusing that just giving the long version, so here goes.

I have a tree inventory that has property quads (in front of a house, to the left, etc) and then a sequence number so that each tree can be identified by its relative location on that property. Also I have street addresses and names among other attributes. My plan is to automate a way to update the sequence numbers.

My current plan to is concatenate a field for each unique location ("Address" + "StreetName" + "Quad".) I will also create another field with those but also the "Sequence_Num" added onto it.

My plan then is to Sort but the second unique field and then create a for loop that selects all trees by the first unique field and then generates an autoIncrement() value.

The problem is that right now I might have several trees with the same exact value for the second unique field (same "Sequence_Num") and I can't be sure it will sort correctly. So I want to find all trees that have the same Unique value for the 4 field concatentation (address, streetname, quad, sequence.)

Short recap, is there any way to find all features that have the same value for a given field?

For ArcGIS.

Comment: Which GIS software you want to use?

Comment: @Midavalo ♦ How can I make this more specific? I feel like what I am asking for is very specific: finding only values in a field with a count > 1

Comment: @nsm91 The new user [tour] states there should be only one question per question, however in asking for a solution for ArcGIS or QGIS you are essentially asking two questions.  Please [edit] your question to focus on one GIS software package.  If you need an answer for both, please ask the two questions separately.

Comment: @Midavalo ♦  I believe I discovered that you can create a summary table and then join it one-to-many to the original feature class, thus allowing you to just select by count > 1, can I edit then answer my own question?

Comment: @nsm91 I'll reopen your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that you can create a summary table of a given field, generating a count field, then use a one-to-many join. Then you would only have to query the count field for > 1.

Comment: if you want to find features with identical field value you can use 'Find Identical' tool in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 0):

If you 'Select Layer By Attribute', you can set up an SQL expression to find all the features that have the same value for a given field. For 'Selection Type' you should probably use ' New Selection', so that way a new column is created based off of the expression that you created.